# Clearing image cache by adding timestamp

Tags: javascript, image, caching, iis, browser-cache

We have a ASP.NET/HTML5 web application. To make sure that after every release, new js and css files are used, we add a parameter to the urls

```
http://myapp.com/public/app.js?rdyyyymmdd
http://myapp.com/public/app.css?rdyyyymmdd
```

But what about image cache which is causing issues. Images are added using `<img>` tag as well as they are being added though css `(background-image)` property.

Now, it is not feasible to add timestamps in css files to all the images. We have hundreds of css files each referencing some images.

So how does one fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could still use a datestamp or GUID. Just add a script to your deployment process which looks for image urls in your compiled css using regex and changes their query string.

Personally I've used Python to do something *kind of* similar, but I'm sure Grunt / Gulp would be a good candidate if you use them.

Comment: already doing that using gulp, looking for an alternate way if possible.